# Replacing a title in xml file with "any"

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file with structure like this:

```
<MyXmlFile>
<FirstTitle>
<SomeItem parameter1="text">
<SecondTitle>
<ThirdTitle>
...
```

Let's say that SecondTitle is named dynamically, so I dont know the name of it. In my code I am checking for existence of ThirdTitle. What I need to do is, loading this into an XmlNodeList. So, in the XmlNodeList declaration, I need to "skip" a part of path to the data in xml. So, if it would be

`XmlNodeList myList = myXmlDocument.SelectNodes("/MyXmlFile/FirstTitle/SecondTitle/ThirdTitle");`

here I need to replace "SecondTitle" with anything, just take anything that comes there.

Comment: Damn, I knew it would be something very simple :D Thanks a lot